# Select the opposite of the union data

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mariadb

I had product, vendor, vendor's available day and booking tables. Currently, my search function only can search through vendor available day, but not search through booking table. I used left joins between vendor and vendor available day and compare with the selected day, time and hour. The search result works. How do I search through booking table?

**Product Table**

```
id | vendor_id | title | description
```

**Vendor Table**

```
id | name
```

**Vendor Available Table**

```
id | vendor_id | d_day | d_start_hour | d_start_minute | d_end_hour | d_end_minute
```

**Booking Table**

```
id | vendor_id | d_date | d_day | d_start_hour | _start_minute
```

Below is how I select product based on the selected day, start_hour and start_minute:

```
SELECT * FROM product
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM vendor GROUP BY id ) vendor 
   ON vendor.id = product.vendor_id
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM vendor_available GROUP BY id) vendor_available 
   ON vendor_available.vendor_id = product.vendor_id
WHERE ( d_day = '4' 
AND (CONCAT(d_start_hour, '.' , d_start_minute) + 0.0) <= '12.15' 
AND (CONCAT(d_end_hour, '.', d_end_minute) + 0.0) >= '12.15')
```

`4` is the selected day and `12.15`  is the selected hour and selected minute on the client side.

When the user selects 12.15 which is 12.15pm, the query will check which product is available between the vendor available time.

**How do I use opposite union with booking table, so that the product which already booked doesn't display to users?**

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

When using `LEFT JOIN tbl`, it is normal to add this to the `WHERE` clause (not the `ON` clause)

```
AND tbl.id IS NULL
```

This says that you want to return results *only* when the is no row in `tbl`.